# Android HttpUrlConnection HttpPost receive a SocketException: no route to host

Tags: android, http-post, httpurlconnection, socketexception

Hey I try to send a HttpPost to an special Device in a local network over wifi. If I try the same code on a simple Java application it will work, but If I try the same code on android I am not able to send the HttpPost.

```
String uri = "http://192.168.3.201:8080/remote/json-rpc/getPeripherals";
Log.i("uri", uri);
String requestBody = "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":"
    + "\"configclient_homedevices/getPeripherals\",\"id\":"
    + "\"1349942076918\",\"params\":[]}";
Log.i("uri", uri);
String contentType = "application/json";
String userpassword = "foo:foo";
String encode = Base64.encodeToString(userpassword.getBytes(),
    Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.DEFAULT);
try {
    URL url = null;
    url = new URL(uri);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" + encode);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
        "" + Integer.toString(requestBody.getBytes().length));
    connection.setUseCaches(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write(requestBody.getBytes());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException ioE) {
    connection.disconnect();
    ioE.printStackTrace();
}
// connection.connect();
try {
    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        Log.i("Status", toString().valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        this.response = response.toString();
        Log.i("Response", response.toString());
    } else {
        Log.i("Status", toString().valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));
        Log.i("Status-message", connection.getResponseMessage());
        connection.disconnect();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this function is in a subclass which extends from AsyncTask. In the Manifest I enabled the Permission.INTERNET

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The result is:

```
10-23 14:52:51.590: W/System.err(5983): java.net.SocketException: No route to host
10-23 14:52:51.590: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
10-23 14:52:51.590: W/System.err(5983):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:369)
10-23 14:52:51.590: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:208)
10-23 14:52:51.590: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:431)
10-23 14:52:51.590: W/System.err(5983):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:901)
10-23 14:52:51.590: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:75)
10-23 14:52:51.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
10-23 14:52:51.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:304)
10-23 14:52:51.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
10-23 14:52:51.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
10-23 14:52:51.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
10-23 14:52:51.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
10-23 14:52:51.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:624)
10-23 14:52:51.600: W/System.err(5983):     at com.febro.myfoo.fooLoginActivitiy$MakeConnection.doInBackground(fooLoginActivitiy.java:339)
10-23 14:52:51.610: W/System.err(5983):     at com.febro.myfoo.fooLoginActivitiy$MakeConnection.doInBackground(fooLoginActivitiy.java:1)
10-23 14:52:51.610: W/System.err(5983):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
10-23 14:52:51.610: W/System.err(5983):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-23 14:52:51.610: W/System.err(5983):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-23 14:52:51.610: W/System.err(5983):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
10-23 14:52:51.610: W/System.err(5983):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
10-23 14:52:51.610: W/System.err(5983):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983): java.net.SocketException: No route to host
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:369)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:208)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:431)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:901)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:75)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:304)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1038)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:736)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at com.febro.myfoo.fooLoginActivitiy$MakeConnection.doInBackground(fooLoginActivitiy.java:351)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at com.febro.myfoo.fooLoginActivitiy$MakeConnection.doInBackground(fooLoginActivitiy.java:1)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
10-23 14:52:54.600: W/System.err(5983):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-23 14:52:54.610: W/System.err(5983):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-23 14:52:54.610: W/System.err(5983):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
10-23 14:52:54.610: W/System.err(5983):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
10-23 14:52:54.610: W/System.err(5983):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

The Exception is thrown at

```
out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: seems like you're just not connected to the internet

Comment: can you connect to the target URL from a web browser running on the test device?

Comment: yes I am able to make a connection over the local wifi to the device over the browser. I can call the url but not the post-request, cause I am not able to put the POST-Message in the request via browser. But this should be normal. If I try it over a java application over my notebook I got a result. By the way I switched the target system and it is the same issue.

Comment: I'm curious of why you instantiate `DataOutputStream`, if you remove that line does it work? Comment out this line `DataOutputStream out = null;`. Documentation: "A DataOutputStream can not be instantiated directly, instead an instance must be created through the static method `createDataOutputStream(OutputStream out, int endianess)`"

Comment: I am using the java.io lib and there is no method called createDataOutputStream. Did you really think this is a problem?

Comment: I don't think you need the method really, I have used `DataOutputStream` and never needed to instantiate. I'd remove that line and just call `DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());` and test, then you can `flush` if necessary.

Comment: You might also check out [this tutorial on using Sockets](http://www.happygeek.in/socket-programming-in-android).

Comment: I also think so like Asok, I changed the DataOutputStream to OutputStream: OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); this also not fixed the issue. What I am wondering is why I am not able to get the OutputStream? I am using the same code like developer.android see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: @user166438 I think you need to look into `Socket`s, your URL has a TCP protocol port 8080 which, to my best knowledge, any TCP connection requires you to use `Socket`s to open the connection. I tried looking for a tutorial that went over `Socket` with a URL Substring, but I wasn't able to come across any. **Note** that I am not familiar with `Socket` connections in Android, so forgive me if I am wrong. See my tutorial link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my Issue. The Issue was a **fixed IP adress** in the url after changing this I received a **Status Code 400 Bad Request**. This issue I got before I switched the request to a async task subclass. The solution for the Bad Request I found in the wireshark protocol. The Client send 2 Hypertext transfer protocols in one http Post. This caused by the **android.Base64.encode()** methode. The encoder inserted a /n after encoding the user:password string. In this case the client sent one http with only basic auth and a second with the rest the body without the basic auth. So the server could not read the request.

To change this you should write **android.Base64.encode(NO_WARP)** this Flag will encode the username:password right.

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when you connect your mobile via different network than your PC. Different networks can have different firewall rules.

PC is typically connected via internal network (typically Ethernet). While mobile phones are usually connected via WIFI with stronger firewall rules.

BTW as the error is: `java.net.SocketException: No route to host` This has nothing to do with GET vs. POST. HTTP GET or POST is communicated to the server later after client is able to connect.

Comment: No I did not think that this is the solution for this issue. I use also wifi on the notebook.